# When using .play() for audio the sound dose not always play

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, web-testing

[Problem spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZsAF.jpg)

If I click it really fast five times it only makes two sounds when it should make five sounds. I am using the .play() method and I have attached a picture of the code so you can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the sound before playing it again:

```
sound.currentTime=0 // just copy-paste this line
sound.play();
```